# ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor is not closing after elapsing maxInactivityDuration setting

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue, spring-jms

I'm implementing ActiveMQ in my application. I have a use case where in when there is no messages in the remote listening queue i need to close the activeMQ connection and I have to reopen the connection when there is a message. I know just setting maxInactivityDuration=30000 will not help me to achieve this use case but atleast its not closing the connection after elapsing the 30 seconds timeout setting. Please let me know what is wrong in this connection and also let me know how i can achieve my use case. Thank you for the solution.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ImportResource("classpath*:beans.xml")
public class MessagingConfiguration {   


    @Value("${activemq.broker.url}")
    private String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000";

    @Value("${activemq.request.queue}")
    private String REQUEST_QUEUE = "test.request";

    @Value("${activemq.response.queue}")
    private String RESPONSE_QUEUE = "test.response";

    @Value("${activemq.borker.username}")
    private String BROKER_USERNAME = "admin";

    @Value("${activemq.borker.password}")
    private String BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin"; 

    @Autowired
    ListenerClass messageListener;

    @Autowired
    JmsExceptionListener jmsExceptionListener;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(3); // Wait 5 seconds first re-delivery, then 15, 45 seconds
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(5000);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(3);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        connectionFactory.setExceptionListener(jmsExceptionListener);
        connectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(100);
        connectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
        connectionFactory.setCacheProducers(false);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(REQUEST_QUEUE);
        template.setSessionAcknowledgeModeName("CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE");
        template.setMessageConverter(converter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer factory = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        factory.setDestinationName(RESPONSE_QUEUE);
        factory.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        factory.setExceptionListener(jmsExceptionListener);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

}
```

**Console logs:**

```
Aug 20, 2017 5:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 61255 ms
17:24:52.216 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:24:52.216 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:24:53.145 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
17:24:53.145 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:24:56.134 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:24:56.134 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:24:56.336 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
17:24:56.336 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:00.252 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:00.257 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:02.217 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:02.217 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:03.145 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor ReadCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - 30001ms elapsed since last read check.
17:25:03.146 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:03.146 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:03.262 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:03.262 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:06.133 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor ReadCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - 30001ms elapsed since last read check.
17:25:06.135 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:06.135 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:06.337 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:06.337 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
17:25:10.253 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10001ms elapsed since last write check.
17:25:10.253 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
```

Comment: What is maxInactivityDuration set to on the broker's transport? If it is zero you will be out of luck, because the broker will take the minimum of the client and broker settings, and zero means "disable inactivity timer". As for the substantive question -- when you say that you want a connection to be closed where there are no messages, do you mean that you want the _broker_ to close it, or that you want the _client_ to close it?

Comment: The current setting is 30 secs ( tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000 ) . I would like the broker close the connection and reopen when there is message in the listener queue.

Comment: maxInactivityDuration can be set on both the broker and the client ends of the connection. The lowest value will be taken. If one of the values is zero, then that will always be the lowest, and inactivity monitoring is disable. I don't know how your broker is set up, so I don't know how likely to is to have maxInactivityDuration set on the transport connector.

Comment: Connections to the broker have to be initiated by a client. If the broker closed the client's connection when there were no messages available, then that would just leave the client stranded with no connection. Perhaps you need to re-work the client so that it uses a receive with timeout? That way, the client would know when messages were available, and could manage its connections accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as per your code, you have registered a listener for the connection so it wont be in an idle state hence wont be closed.

But if you want to forcefully close the connection then you may need to set maxTimeout for your connection.

Comment: Can you tell me exact setting because i couldn't find this setting. I tried failover transport (timeout=3000) setting but it didn't work.